# Javascript Combine Binary Flags

Tags: javascript, titanium, appcelerator

I'm trying to combine javascript binary flags inline with my var definition but my code throws an exception "Can't find variable: A".  Is there a way to accomplish this?

```
var flag = {
    A: 1,
    B: 2,
    C: 4,
    D: 8,
    All: A | B | C | D,
};
```

Comment: This isn't a problem with your math, it's a problem with how you're declaring things. You can't use `A` while you're still declaring the object containing `A`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use `A` while you're still declaring the object that contains `A`.

If you want to use those values, you need to declare (or initialize) the `All` field later, like so:

```
var flag = {
    A: 1,
    B: 2,
    C: 4,
    D: 8,
};
flag.All = flag.A | flag.B | flag.C | flag.D;
```

Alternately, you can use a function as a scope to enclose the variables, and do something like:

```
var flag = (function () {
  var A = 1, B = 2, C = 4, D = 8;
  return {A: A, B: B, C: C, D: D, All: A|B|C|D};
}());
```

The ES6 object shorthand makes this much more attractive:

```
var flag = (function () {
  var A = 1, B = 2, C = 4, D = 8;
  return {A, B, C, D, All: A|B|C|D};
}());
```

If `All` is a common pattern for you, it's possible to generate that:

```
flag.All = Object.keys(flag).reduce(function (p, c) { 
  return p | flag[c]; 
}, 0);
```

With ES6, you can shorten that as well:

```
flag.All = Object.keys(flag).reduce((p, c) => (p | flag[c]), 0);
```

If ES6 is available to you, try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30759014/129032) for declaring enums. The above methods for creating an `All` value will work with it, but it provides more of the traditional enum semantics you might expect (especially being read-only).

Comment: Great answers.  I didn't try them all.  The first one works but gets long when I have many flags and descriptive names.  Love the reduce option!  That's one I will add to my toolbox.  Thanks.